# Using a UISegmentedControl like a UISwitch

Tags: swift, switch-statement, uisegmentedcontrol

Is it possible to use a `UISegmentedControl` with 3 segments as if it was a three-way `UISwitch`? I tried to use one as a currency selector in the settings section of my app with no luck, it keeps reseting to the first segment when I switch views and that creates a big mess.

I proceeded like that:

```
IBAction func currencySelection(_ sender: Any) {
    switch segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        WalletViewController.currencyUSD = true
        WalletViewController.currencyEUR = false
        WalletViewController.currencyGBP = false
        MainViewController().refreshPrices()
        print(0)
    case 1:
        WalletViewController.currencyUSD = false
        WalletViewController.currencyEUR = true
        WalletViewController.currencyGBP = false
        MainViewController().refreshPrices()
        print(1)
    case 2:
        WalletViewController.currencyUSD = false
        WalletViewController.currencyEUR = false
        WalletViewController.currencyGBP = true
        MainViewController().refreshPrices()
        print(2)
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: You can save state to UserDefaults and read every time view apper

Comment: (1) Sure you can. As long as only *one* switch state is possible, a segmented control can be used. (2) My instincts say you aren't doing something correctly. But it's hard to say exactly what based on the code posted. What is `refreshPrices` doing? Why is it part of another view controller? And what do you mean by *"when I switch views"*? I'm thinking it's somewhere in code *not* posted that you are resetting the segmented control. (3) If you think of the segmented control as a three way switch, then the `switch` code you posted is not needed. Just look at the `selectedSegmentIndex`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Masiama I successfully saved the `UISegmentedControl` state using `UserDefaults` on `segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex`.

Comment: @dfd `refreshPrices` is used to refresh the values and `NumberFormatter` of the prices displayed on the `MainViewController` depending of the `UISegmentedControl`'s currency selection. I'm sure I am not doing anything as simply as I could tho haha. I use the `switch-case` logic to get variables I can then use anywhere in the project when I need to load either or currency. Maybe I could just use the `segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex` value for that?

Comment: I just posted an answer. A comment you made on another answer shed light on what you're trying to do. In it I'm recommending setting up a delegate and presenting the settings VC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The `UISegmentedControl` is implemented in the
>   `SettingsViewController` of the app to choose between currencies to
>   display in the `MainViewController`.

(Taken from a comment in @pacification's answer.)

This was the missing piece I was looking for. It provides a lot of context.

**TL;DR;**

Yes, you can use a three segment `UISegmentedControl` as a three-way switch. The only *real* requirement is that you can have *only* one value or state selected.

But I wasn't grasping why your code referred to two view controllers and some of switching views resulting in resetting the segment. One very good way to do what you want is to:

- Have `MainViewController` *present* `SettingsViewController`. Presenting it modally means the user is only doing one thing at a time. When they are making setting changes, you do not want them adding new currency values.
- Create a delegate protocol in `SettingsViewController` and make `MainViewController` conform to it. This tightly-couples changes made to the settings to the view controller interested in what those changes are.

Here's a template for what I'm talking about:

**SettingsViewController:**

```
protocol SettingsVCDelegate {
    func currencyChanged(sender: SettingsViewController)
}
class SettingsViewController : UIViewController {

    var delegate:SettingsVCDelegate! = nil
    var currency:Int = 0    
    @IBAction func valueChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        currency = sender.selectSegmentIndex
        delegate.currencyChanged(sender:self)
    }
}
```

**MainViewController:**

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, SettingsVCDelegate {
    var currency:Int = 0
    let settingsVC = SettingsViewController()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        settingsVC.delegate = self
    }
    func presentSettings() {
        present(settingsVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    func currencyChanged(sender:SettingsViewController) {
        currency = sender.currency
    }
}
```

You can also create an `enum` of type `Int` to make your code more readable, naming each value as `currencyUSD`, `currencyEUR`, and `currencyGBP`. I'll leave that to you as a learning exercise.

Answer (score 0):

> it keeps reseting to the first segment when I switch views

yes, it is. to avoid this situation you should set the correct switch value to the `segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex` every time when you load your view with `UISegmentedControl`.

**UPD**

Ok, the behavior of `MainViewController` can be similar to this:

```
final class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    private var savedValue = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func openSettingsController() {
        let viewController = SettingsController.instantiate() // simplify code a bit. use the full controller initialization
        viewController.configure(value: savedValue, onValueChanged: { [unowned self] value in
            self.savedValue = value
        })
        navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
    }

}
```

And the `SettingsViewController`:

```
final class SettingsViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!

    private var value: Int = 0

    var onValueChanged: ((Int) -> Void)?

    func configure(value: Int, onValueChanged: @escaping ((Int) -> Void)) {
        self.value = value
        self.onValueChanged = onValueChanged
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = value
    }

    @IBAction func valueChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        onValueChanged?(sender.selectedSegmentIndex)
    }

}
```

The main idea that you should keep your selected value if you moving from `SettingsViewController`. For this thing you can create closure

```
var onValueChanged: ((Int) -> Void)?
```

that pass back to `MainViewController` the selected `UISegmentedControl` value. And in future when you will open the `SettingsViewController` again you just `configure()` this value and set it to UI.

Comment: So I don't need my `WalletViewController.currency` variables and just set `segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex` in the `switch` statement?

Comment: I mean if you selected `currencyEUR` (the second one), pop your controller back and again open the controller with `UISegmentedControl`, it always switched to the first value (initial state). in this case you need manually set `selectedSegmentIndex`.

Comment: I am sorry but could you please show me an example in code?

Comment: By the way I am not popping any view with `UISegmentedControl`. I am just using it as a three-way `UISwitch` to load different data in functions.

Comment: @Martin33000, when exactly `UISegmentedControl` changed back to initial value?

Comment: The `UISegmentedControl` is implemented in the `SettingsViewController` of the app to choose between currencies to display in the `MainViewController`. So when I select let say the second segment of the  `UISegmentedControl`, go back to the `MainViewController` and then load the `SettingsViewController` again, the `UISegmentedControl` changed back to it's initial value.

Comment: Thank you very much! Seems a bit complicated for me, I successfully saved the state with `UserDefaults`